# Composer fails due to missing depends

Tags: php, linux, atom-editor

I'm trying to make Atom, my IDE, work as a full-featured PHP IDE.

The best way to do this seems to be the 'php-integrator' package.
(https://php-integrator.github.io/)

Researching this error it seems that Composer may be the problem. I'll attach a screenshot of an Ubuntu terminal command to show you the error.

I can't find the missing packages and really just want this to work painlessly. What can I do?
[image]

Comment: where is your screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry. Thanks so much!

Comment: have you tried with --with-dependencies flag ?

Comment: Good idea. Personally I managed to guess the right packages in the end.